# Duplicate flag declined

Tags: support, flagging

These two are ditto duplicates,

[The Function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586331/the-function-f-mathbbr2-rightarrow-mathbbr2-defined-by-fr-theta)

[On which open set $f$ admits an inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586259/on-which-open-set-f-admits-an-inverse)

Just that one has a lot of typos. I flagged them and the flag was declined. What's happening?

Comment: FYI: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/643837

Comment: @JohnMa,are duplicate flags processed in close flag queue? Also, interestingly, the questioner of one of them has answered the second!

Comment: Doesn't that make sense? You want to close the question because it is a duplicate.

Comment: As Travis observed many things point at the question mixing domain and codomain. Because of that I would be inclined to close both as unclear.

Comment: @JohnMa, what convinced you to vote it as Leave Open?

Comment: @JessePFrancis I did not vote this one.

Comment: @JohnMa, confused you with JohnMarkPerry, sorry!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, This is from CSIR NET, a bi-annual examination in India qualifying one for Lectureship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duplicate flag (as any close flag) puts the question in the close-review queue where it is processed by users (not moderators specifically, though a moderator can do reviews in the close-queue too).

The status of the flag is decided based on the outcome of the review.

The flag was declined because three users voted "Leave Open" in the review queue as can be seen on the [review-card](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/643837) linked to by John Ma. The three LO votes mean that the review is completed, with the outcome not in line with the flag (close as duplicate) it is thus marked declined.

This is the technical side of things. Why those users decided to vote leave open is hard to know. But in my experience the fact that something is proposed to be a closed as a *duplicate* (rather than for some other reasons) is something one can reasonably overlook. Thus, I'd speculate that the users just did not notice it was a vote for a duplicate and the vote to LO are against a general closure.

Comment: now, what is to be done? Jyrki suggests closing both as unclear!

Comment: Myself I'd speculate that some of these users are robo-reviewers who cast a large number of "Leave Open" votes in a very short window of time, with a few seconds between each vote. "Leave Open" is quicker to cast than "Close".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I think the badges are a big motivating factor for many of such reviews. Do the SE engine show any warning to users who more frequently vote "Leave Open"?

Comment: @JessePFrancis Not as far as I know. If you see it happen you can leave flag for mod attention for really egregious cases, but otherwise there's not much one can do, and I don't think there's any kind of automated system in place.

Comment: @Najib: That is probable. I once clocked myself, however, and a few seconds is often enough. With duplicates, however, I do agree that a few seconds is usually not enough, as some additional attention needs to be given to the content of both threads.